# Insert Ignore Into Mysql with a Primary Key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, insert-into

I am trying to use INSERT IGNORE INTO to add a row to a table if it doesn't already exist.
Here is the statement as it stands right now:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (integer, date) VALUES (11111, CURDATE())
```

However, since I have an auto-incrementing primary key on the table (that is not part of the insert of course), it always does the insert.  Is there a way to disregard the primary key so that if the integer and date are already in the table it will not insert another row with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a UNIQUE key on the integer and the date, or the combination of the two - whichever fits your needs. That will prevent `INSERT IGNORE` from inserting values that violate the UNIQUE index.

For example if you want to make the combination of the two unique:

```
alter table my_table add unique index(integer, date)
```